# Use burp suite for local wordpress (with xammp).

Tags: windows, xampp, localhost

1- Can i use burp suite for localhost wordpress with xampp in windows?

2- how can i use burp for my localhost wordpress with xampp? my burp don't work for my local system.

Thank you.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142552/how-to-configure-burp-suite-for-localhost-application

Comment: Thank you but this solution didn't work.

Comment: There is not network.security.ports.banned.override in about:config.

Comment: you have to writethat line with the port number .

Comment: how can i write?

Comment: I add network.security.ports.banned.override and 6666. but don't work

Comment: and the browser proxy setting

Comment: set browser proxy  127.0.0.1 - 6666 and burp, but didn't work in my localhost apps.

Comment: check xampp server port and use that '

Comment: now my server xampp and about:config and browser and burp have 127.0.0.1 and 80. Is it true?

Comment: the port number need to be same for both listning and xamp server

Comment: Really sorry, now is not work for local.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong .. ..